# How to achieve this sorting described using mySQL and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table named *"categories"* with three fields as below

```
cat     | order | id
--------|-------|----
News    |  3    | 23
Hi-Tech |  2    | 15
Biz     |  5    | 8
Health  |  1    | 3
```

Also, I have another table named *"links"* like below

```
link    | order | cat-id
--------|-------|-------
link1   |  2    | 23
link2   |  8    | 15
link3   |  5    | 8
link4   |  6    | 15
link5   |  2    | 15
link6   |  4    | 23
link7   |  1    | 3
link8   |  1    | 8
```

What I want to achieve is to sort *categories* and below each category to sort the *links* of that category *cat-id / id* like this below:

**Health**
link7

**Hi-Tech**
link5
link4
link2

**News**
link1
link6

**Biz**
link8
link3

I succeeded on showing the *categories* sorted but I am loosing it after it.

**My aim is to show this on a page so I guess I have to use PHP and mySQL.**

Comment: sql query only or PHP & SQL ?

Comment: @UserB I have updated my question. My aim is to show this on a page so I guess I have to use PHP and mySQL.

Comment: try my answer with PHP & MySQL

Comment: hey bud, go for paolo's answer, it the best answer for your query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The query is simply this:

```
SELECT c.cat, l.link, c.id
FROM links l INNER JOIN categories c
ON l.cat-id = c.id
ORDER BY c.`order`, l.`order`
```

And [here it is at work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d73c1/2).

In order to show it on a page, it would look like this:

```
mysql_connect(<host>, <username>, <password>);

$q = mysql_query("<query from above>");
$last_cat = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    if($row['id'] != $last_cat) {
        print '<h3>' . $row['cat'] . '</h3>';
        $last_cat = $row['id'];
    }
    print $row['link'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I guess I have to use PHP and mySQL because I will show this on a page.

Comment: I didn't saw your post when I was writing mine, but we used the same aliases and variable names. Interesting.

Comment: Please assume that it will have about 60 rows on "categories" tables and at least 5 links to each category. Is this code optimized for this ?

Comment: @Kaoukkos: In database and programming terms, those numbers are child's play. This code is pretty much the standard way of handling this before you get into paging, etc. It only makes 1 trip to the database and prints everything out in one loop. From a usability perspective 60x5 seems like a bit much to show the user but that is outside the scope of this question...

Comment: @PaoloBergantino: Well, I think after some level and experience, all the coders think the same :)

Comment: Just to add to what @PaoloBergantino has mentioned above. The way you have constructed your table structure is more important than the number of rows. If the links are all in place and the indexes are properly defined, it shouldn't be a problem for mysql to fetch the data for you. To evaluate your query, you could simply use `explain`.

Comment: The only thing I could possibly add to this answer is that if you want a portable format you can build an array from the data `$array[$row['cat']][] = $row['link']` which allows for some fine-tuned manipulation if you so desire.

Comment: @PaoloBergantino thank you for your answer. Before accepting it, can you please tell me where your code excels against this user? http://stackoverflow.com/a/10462415/807325

Comment: @Kaoukkos: His answer unnecessarily loops through the results twice to build an array that makes it 'cleaner' to print the data. Again, with the amount of data you are handling the speed difference is truly irrelevant, but my answer will be the fastest if you still care.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this on my mind so didn't test it, but it kinda goes like this :

```
$q = mysql_query("select * from categories c 
      left join links l 
      on l.cat-id=c.id 
      order by c.order,l.order");

$last_cat = -1;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    if($last_cat!=$row["cat"]){
        echo "<br><b>".$row["cat"]."</b><br>";
        $last_cat=$row["cat"];
    }
    echo $row["link"]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Please assume that it will have about 60 rows on "categories" tables and at least 5 links to each category. Is this code optimized for this ?

Comment: Yes, the sql will return the most effective result and the PHP will execute it in just one loop. It won't matter if there are hundreds of links. I'm using this method for listing tv show episodes. Think about it.

Comment: You forgot to change last_cat when a category changes =)

Answer (score 2):

This will print exactly as you have described in the example:

```
<?php
$categories = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories order by 'order'");
$links = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links order by 'order'"); 
?>

<?php foreach ($categories as $key => $category): ?>
 <b><?php echo $category['cat'];?>"</b>
    <?php foreach ($links as $key => $link): ?>
      <?php if($category['id'] === $link['cat-id']): ?>
         <?php echo $link['link'];?>
      <?php endif;?>
    <?php endforeach;?>
   <br />
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// This query gets all the needed data with one shot. No need to do multiple
// queries. You can run this query in phpMyAdmin to see the result.
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT links.link as link, categories.cat as cat FROM links
    LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id = links.cat_id
    ORDER BY categories.order, links.order ASC");

// With this we are getting all links with correct order to an array.
$categories = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $categories[$row['cat']][] = $row['link'];
}

// To see how we stored the links in the array uncomment the below line
// var_dump($categories);

// To print out the data:
foreach ($categories as $category => $links) {
    echo "<strong>".$category."</strong><br />\n";

    // implode is a built-in function that makes a string from an array.
    // You can put something between the array elements with the first parameter.
    // If you want to make some changes or print the links, use a foreach loop.
    echo implode("<br />\n", $links)."<br /><br />\n";
}
?>
```

This should write the links exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY categories.order ASC, links.order ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select cat, link
from categories, links
where link.cat-id = categories.id
order by cat asc, link asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your query and if we need to think optmization we will consider some cases

**case 1:** 
As you have mentioned you would have 60(links) * 5 (categories), these are very ease to handle from mysql side itself. We can very well use our SQL techniques itself and get the advantage from it.

Always you can have a mixture of php processing + SQL. The processing speed of PHP is faster than mysql. sO, GRAB IT.

Your query can also be solved by SQl alone and the query mentioned by paolo can be used simply.

**case 2:**
There are situation where either or both  one of the table participating tables have too high number of records. when there is a join between them it results into high number of combinations i.e join size
eg: links(100000) * categories(10) = 1 million
In these cases, u can try to avoid joins.

You can take advantage of indexes.
Indexes are used to find rows with specific column values quickly. Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows.

There are techniques like flat files i.e schema free databases like MongoDB which dont use concept of joins but if you plan on it running it on a huge site (huge, meaning that you need many many servers to host it)

MySQl scales well and you have to think something out of it when you are in a huuuuuuuge environment.

**Here,I have solved your query without using joins and any dependent query. I have just fetch  results and just used array mapping techniques only which is faster.**

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category order by `order` asc");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
     $categories[$row['id']]['cat']  = $row['cat'];
     $categories[$row['id']]['order'] = $row['order'];

 } 

 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY `order` ASC ");
 $count =0; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ) {
     $links[$row['cat-id']][$count]['link']  = $row['link'];
     $links[$row['cat-id']][$count]['order']  = $row['order'];
     $links[$row['cat-id']][$count]['cat-id']  = $row['cat-id'];
     $count++; 
 } 

foreach ($categories as $id=$value) {
     foreach ($links[$id] as $link_info) {

         if ($last_cat != $link_info['cat-id'])
             print '<h3' . $categories[$link_info['cat-id']]['cat'] . '</h3';

         print $link_info['link'] . '<br';
         $last_cat = $link_info['cat-id'];
     } }
```

Answer (score 0):

1st the query as a lot of people says its:

```
SELECT c.cat,c.order as catorder,c.id,l.* FROM categories as c 
INNER JOIN links as l ON (c.id = l.id-cat )
ORDER BY c.order, l.order
```

so u have a result ordered like this:

```
cat     | catorder | id  |  link   | order | cat-id
--------|----------|-----|---------|-------|-------
Health  |  1       | 3   |  link7  |  1    |  3
Hi-Tech |  2       | 15  |  link5  |  2    |  15
Hi-Tech |  2       | 15  |  link4  |  6    |  15
Hi-Tech |  2       | 15  |  link2  |  8    |  15
News    |  3       | 23  |  link1  |  2    |  23
News    |  3       | 23  |  link6  |  4    |  23
Biz     |  5       | 8   |  link8  |  1    |  8
Biz     |  5       | 8   |  link3  |  1    |  8
```

So .. you need to make a "cutting control"

```
$max = sizeof($arrayOfResults)
$i = 0;
while ($i < $max) {
    $current = $arrayOfResults[$i]["id"];
    print_r($arrayOfResults[$current]["cat"]);
    while ($i < $max && $arrayOfResults[$i]["id"] == $current) {
        print_r($arrayOfResults[$current]["link"]);
        $i++;
    }
}
```

If u copy and paste this code u going to have the output that u r searching.

If u need a explanation ask me.

Answer (score -1):

code may be like this.

```
<?php
$result_catg = mysql_query("select * from categories order by order asc");
?>
<ul>
<?php
while($row_catg = mysql_fetch_array($result_catg))
{
$catg_id = $row_catg['id'];
$result_link = mysql_query("select * from links where cat_id = '$catg_id' order by order asc");
while($row_link = mysql_fetch_array($result_link))
{
?>
<li class="down"><?php echo $row_link['link']; ?></li>
<?php
}
}
?>
</ul>
```

just use "float:none " in your css property for **li down**

hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the required result.

```
$ds = mysql_query("select cat, id from categories order by  'order' asc");
while($rs = mysql_fetch_row($ds))
{
    echo"<b>".$rs[0]."<b><br/>";
    $dsLinks = mysql_query("select link from links where cat_id = '".$rs[1]."' order by 'order' asc");
    while($rsLink = mysql_fetch_row($ds))
    {
        echo"<b>".$rsLink [0]."<b><br/>";
    }
    echo"<br/>";
}
```

Comment: A query in a loop isn't a good solution : with 100 rows in your categories table, you do 101 queries ! You have to use inner-join in this case, look Paolo Bergantino's query ;-)